# Anyway of having captureOutput callback on a Background Thread?

Tags: iphone, audio-recording

Is there anyway to have the OS callback the delegate

```
         - (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)psampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)pconnection
```

on a background thread instead of the main thread?  The issue is the time that it is taking to  copy off the data is affecting the UI.  This seems to have to be done on the main thread since  the captureOutput seems to be gone if trying to copy it in a background thread, etc... Am I missing something here?

```
        CMFormatDescriptionRef format;
        format = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);
        bufSize = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer);
        sampleSize = CMSampleBufferGetSampleSize(sampleBuffer,0);
        sampleLength = CMSampleBufferGetTotalSampleSize(sampleBuffer);
        blockbuff = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer);

        CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(blockbuff, 0, tocopy*_depth, buffInUse+(offset*2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a good answer, this seems to get the location to fix the callback thread

```
     [audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Just need to change the queue.

Comment: did you miss something, you want the callback to be called on the background thread, but then you use main queue ?

Comment: So long ago, just plain don't remember the details.  It was a UI performance problem.  I think that I had this as an example on how to change if need be.

Answer (score 1):

I use CVPixelBuffer functions to lock/unlock the buffer and get image format information. I use memcpy to copy the data (while the buffer is locked) and call performSelectorInBackground to process the data.

Comment: Turns out the delay that I was seeing was due to a @syncronized(self) that I code from other's code somehow.  Changing this to @synchronized(s) where s is a NSString * solved the delay problem.  Not sure why this is, but FYI